# Array de Input HTML e Django Request.POST

Tags: html, ajax, django

Estou tentando fazer um POST com FormData pra uma view e não estou conseguindo pegar o **array de input**. Segue o exemplo:

**HTML**

```
<input name="bonus" type="number" placeholder="ex.: 100.000,00">
{% for x in 'xxxxx' %}
    <input name="pontos[]" type="number" placeholder="ex.: 100.000,00">
    <input name="nomes[]" type="text" price placeholder="ex.: 1.000,00">
{% endfor %}
```

**views.py**

```
bonus = request.POST.get('bonus', None)
pontos = request.POST.getlist('pontos[]', None)
nomes = request.POST.getlist('nomes[]', None)
print(bonus, pontos, nomes)
```

**output**

```
>>> 10 [None] [None]
```

Quanto faço um print no `request.POST` aparece isso:

```
<QueryDict: { 'bonus': 10, 'pontos[]': [None], 'nomes[]': [None]}>
```

Vendo no Network do Chrome, está indo todos os campos certinho.

```
bonus: 10.00
pontos[]: 10000
pontos[]: 100100110
pontos[]: 
pontos[]: 
pontos[]: 
nomes[]: Guilherme
nomes[]: Joao
nomes[]: 
nomes[]: 
nomes[]:
```

Comment: No back vc está resgatando como array, mas está enviando apenas o último campo preenchido, pois todos os nomes serão iguais no laço. Tente trocar o nome do campo para `pontos[]` e `nomes[]` respectivamente, assim os tornará um array.

Comment: @GiovanCruz fiz a modificação (ja tinha testado antes) e o print é `10 [None] [None]`... Estranho que o outro campo pega, agora esse de array não.. será que tem algo relacionado a usar FormData?